# Rewriting Get URLs PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I know there are multiple question about it have looked around but cant get it working

i have url `www.example.com/order.php?view=Draft`  rewrite to `www.example.com/order.php/Draft`

I have the following on .htaccess

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)$ order.php?view=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My links are as follows in the `<a>` tag
`www.mysite.com/order/view/Draft`

I am getting a too many redirects error.

**EDIT**

Successfully managed. used

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^view/([^/\.]+)/?$ order.php?view=$1 [L]
```

for my link `<a href="view/Draft">`

also remember to add 
`<base href="https://www.example.org/" />` just after the head tag to get the correct js and css links

Answer (score 1):

If need to redirect just one url to another you can use the following

```
Redirect "www.mysite.com/order.php?view=Draft" "www.mysite.com/order.php/Draft"
```

Comment: makes sense. What if the get variable is generated dynamically?

Comment: No, what is currently shown here, does _not_ make sense. The `Redirect` directive does prefix-matching on the _path_ component of the URL. `www.mysite.com` is not part of the path. And neither is `?view=Draft`, that is the query string - and that you _can not_ match on at this point, with this directive.